What is the impact of increasing batch_size_fail_threshold?
I see this post  which recommends not to increase these values but I have a requirement from application to increase it to the below threshold.
Could you please let me know what is the impact if I change the batch size warning and failure as below. Do I need to check/update any other parameters while increasing this threshold.
Cassandra version 3.11.13?
Default value:
batch_size_warn_threshold: 5KiB
batch_size_fail_threshold: 50KiB 

To:
batch_size_warn_threshold: 50KiB
batch_size_fail_threshold: 100KiB 


Large batches put a strain on the coordinator of the write request because it has more data to handle (also stated in the post you quoted). Anytime a node processes data, it puts pressure on the JVM heap as the data is serialised/deserialised.
Having said that, a batch size of 100KB is pretty small in the greater scheme of things. As always, you should test it first with production-like workloads to see how it performs so you can make an educated judgement. Cheers!

Thanks for the response @Erick

Happy to help. Just a friendly reminder since you're new to the site that you need to take the next steps when someone answers your question. Details here -- https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. Cheers!
